# How to place text centered and above images

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I'm new to coding with html and css and I'm stuck on getting my text to be centered and above images, I'm using flexbox to accomplish this. I tried searching all over but no luck.

Here is a screenshot on what I'm trying to accomplish -> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvJCP.jpg)

P.s I have "Display: flex;" enabled for all my main content, the code you see below is  part of my main content

```css
.OurPartners {
        text-align: center;
        color: white
        background-color: #005c9b;
        Height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        order: 3;
        
        align-items: center;
    }

    .Ourpartner_text {
        flex-wrap: wrap
        width: 100%;
        order: 2;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
       
        
    }
    .OurPartners img {
   order:1;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 220px
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="OurPartners">
    <div class= "OurPartners_text"><h1>Our Partners</h1></div>
   
    <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AHRCFoundationLogo_White.png" alt="test" >
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/BCCSLogo_White.png.webp" > 
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CitizensLogo_White.png.webp" >
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CL-Program-of-Transparent-Background-005.png.webp">
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AvantageCarelogo_White.png.webp" > 
</div>
```

Comment: We cannot change our HTML. Right? Or can we?

Comment:  Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/1zmvpqb5/ 

Comment: you have multiple typos and missing semicolons within your CSS code. line 3: missing semicolon, line 12: 2 typos of the class name, line 13: missing semicolon, line 27: missing semicolon...

Answer (score 1):

The snippet solve this with CSS-Grid. However you have multiple spelling (typo) errors aswell as missing semicolon in your code. Also you have a size problem. The container height and width is less then the content height and width which also causes an styling issue.

Missing semicolon:

- line 3: `color: white`
- line 13: `flex-wrap: wrap`
- line 27: `width: 220px`

Spelliny Error / Typos:

- line 12: `.Ourpartner_text {` shoud be -> `OurPartners_text {`

```css
.OurPartners {
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
  background-color: #005c9b;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 220px);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  width: min-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.OurPartners_text {
  grid-column: span 5;
}

.OurPartners img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="OurPartners">
  <div class="OurPartners_text">
    <h1>Our Partners</h1>
  </div>

  <img src="https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AHRCFoundationLogo_White.png" alt="test">
  <img src="https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/BCCSLogo_White.png.webp">
  <img src="https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CitizensLogo_White.png.webp">
  <img src="https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CL-Program-of-Transparent-Background-005.png.webp">
  <img src="https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AvantageCarelogo_White.png.webp">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. I was dong the same.Now that you have answered. I am rating your answer my Friend :) No need for me to answer now. :)

Comment: yes this works after editing both the CSS code and HTML code you provided. question, when assigning different "DIV's" to the same container you just need one closing "<DIV>" tag? ALSO, how do I add more space between "Our Partner" heading and the images?

Comment: the space between the header and the images can be increased or decresed with: `grid-column-gap: 10px;`. This line currently adds a gap of 10px. you can insert a value what ever you like there. A div is not an empty tag, therefor always need a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

CSS:

```
.OurPartners {
    text-align: center;
    color: white background-color: #005c9b;
    Height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    order: 3;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative; // <--------- New code
    padding-top: 58px; // < --------- New code
}

// <-------- New code ------------->
 .OurPartners_text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

position your text absolutely, this way will not affect the other elements in the container, and use width: 100%, top: 0; and text-align: center, also added 18% width to the images this way you will have 2% space between the images and will not run out of the container, this in case if you have 5 images.

```css
.OurPartners {
        color: white;
        background-color: #555;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .OurPartners_text {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
       
        
    }
    .OurPartners img {
    width: 18%;
    height: auto;
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="OurPartners">
    <div class= "OurPartners_text"><h1>Our Partners</h1></div>
   
    <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AHRCFoundationLogo_White.png" alt="test" >
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/BCCSLogo_White.png.webp" > 
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CitizensLogo_White.png.webp" >
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/CL-Program-of-Transparent-Background-005.png.webp">
     <img src= "https://www.ahrc.org/wp-content/uploads/AvantageCarelogo_White.png.webp" > 
</div>
```